# how to display msg in textbox if the selected record could not be found in database 

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have two textboxes and 1 button ...

i m doing when i enter travel id in textbox1 and click on button1 then in textbox2 i retrieve the travel agency name according to the travel id i entered in textbox1,

I want when no record is found according to the travel id i entered in textbox1 then in textbox2 it shows the message no record found ...

this is coding i use to retrieve record in textbox2 by enter travel id in textbox1 : have a look ...

***Please re-edit this code according to my query above :***

```
Protected Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

        Dim SQLData As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
        Dim cmdSelect As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM a1_vendors WHERE VendorId ='" & TextBox1.Text & "'", SQLData)

        SQLData.Open()
        Dim dtrReader As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader()
        If dtrReader.HasRows Then
            While dtrReader.Read()
                TextBox2.Text = dtrReader("travels")
            End While
        Else
            '
        End If

        dtrReader.Close()
        SQLData.Close()
        End Sub
```

Comment: What about `TextBox2.Text = "No records found"` in the empty `ELSE` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to add in the else block:

TextBox2.Text="No records found".